# How to resize image by one axis given a vector in form of 1d gradient?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-scaling

I have an image (source) with size WxH. I have a vector of floating-point numbers 0-N of length W. I want to scale the original image column by column so that if the vector value is less than one it would shrink and if greater it would expand. How to do such a thing in Python?

So Having a set of numbers 0,..0, 1,..1, 3,..3 and an image like this:

[image]

we would get a new image like this (its  size can be different from original

[image]

Comment: How will you handle the sizes?  In a numpy array, all columns have to be the same size.  You can certainly resample the columns individually, but where will you put the results?

Comment: So some columns will get taller and some shorter? And will the resulting columns line up at the top, bottom or in the middle? Will the image be transparent where columns don't reach top or bottom edge?

Comment: `np.cumsum()`, round the values, use as lookup indices. ... perhaps use 1/value instead of value. numpy also has ways to "replicate" values... if you need interpolation, that can be arranged too. construct maps suitable for `cv::remap`.